# Adapt the heigh of an iframe window for an embedded chat inside a VFP

Tags: visualforce, css, experience-cloud

I'm integrating an embedded chat using a VFP in Experience cloud site. (Only solution proposed by Salesforce as the chat is interacting with another Salesforce org).

[image]

The button is configured within Experience cloud builder using VFP and this css so that the button can move with me when i scroll down :

> {
> z-index:999;
> width: fit-content;
> position:fixed;
> right: 0;
> bottom: 0;
> }

The problem i'm facing is that the VFP iFrame is preventing click-on links (see screenshot). In fact, i can no longer click on links under the related links box. I tried to reduce the height of the VFP but if i do so i can no longer see correctly the inside of the chat button.
[image]

**UPDATE**

I see that event without having z-index property applied to the VF component of the experience builder. Its height only is sufficient to overlay the components.

So i changed its height to 100px something smaller and i'm trying to use some chat Event (afterMaximize to try and increase this height dynamically to be able to see the button).

```
 embedded_svc.addEventHandler("afterMaximize", function(data) {
                    console.log("afterMaximize event was fired.",document.getElementsByName('vfFrameId_1652794789149') );
                   
                });
```

But still i can't find how to target the iframe parent. Even document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") doest get me the parent iframe of document
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I used event AfterMaximize and AfterMinimize from chat event notifications , got the parent Iframe and then changed the height. This is an none elaborated example just to show :

```
embedded_svc.addEventHandler("afterMaximize", function(data) {
                        var iframe = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
                        iframe.height = '550px';
                    });
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_chat_events.htm

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your CSS is being applied to the iFrame and not to just your button. We cannot see all of your solution so it is difficult to be specific - but you need to avoid setting the z-index of the iFrame such that it overlays content on the page and intercepts clicks.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I tried to add the z-index css on the button instead of the Iframe and it does not work the buttton gets hidden :  .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton{
            z-index:999 !important;
            position:fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

Comment: As per VF code its only the generated embedded chat code of Salesforce